# Fill empty space in Inkscape?

Tags: icons, inkscape

I am new to Inkscape, and it is a little complex. I have been trying to make vector/SVG version of PNG icons I am working on. I use Path>Trace Bitmap to create vector versions of my PNG. My issue is that it does not retain the white area within the icon. How can I use Inkscape to fill in the empty area with white?

[image: Left SVG, right PNG]

Left SVG, right PNG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually create a white rectangle which I put in the background of my graphic. You can put this to a seperate layer if you like, so that you don't interfere with it when editing the other stuff.

You can also change the Background color in the `"File" -> "Document Properties"` dialog (on the first tab, named "Page")

but I like the rectangle method more, because sometimes I like to keep parts transparent and I feel it makes me more flexible.

Comment: White rectangle worked perfectly :)